# How to use FormHelper postLink to upload a singlefile in Cake 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, formhelper

This is the postLink method of FormHelper in Cake 2.3.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink

I was wondering if I can use it to upload a single file instead of using it for deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

That function creates a form that looks like a link. Uploading a file can be achieved with [appropriate usage of the form helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create), e.g.:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('avatar');
echo $this->Form->submit();
```